# How do I create an array of ints using strings for indexing

Tags: c, arrays, integer

I am not sure what this is called, so I don't know what to google to learn how to do this.

I am programming in C.

I have an array of ints, that I am looking to name with chars;

for example

```
char s1[21] = "firsta1"
char s2[21] = "seconds2"
```

etc etc

then array of ints something like, assuming the array of ints is called index.

```
index[s1] = 7
index[s2] = 14
```

etc etc.

thanks,

Comment: You want this in c or what? exactly string you use to find the elements (associate) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is said to be associative arrays. In shell programming we have associative arrays. In c++ and java we can achieve this with Maps [HashMap, TreeMap]

```
Map<Key,Value>
```

key is used to identify the value; Keys should be unique.

I don't think C have built-in facility for this. May be you can achieve this in other way.

You create those strings s[21]="str" ... pass it to some function say hash.

```
   hash(char *str)
   {
      // Keep a cache (a table here its array)
       lookup the string in table;
       if(present)
           return index;           
       else
           store str in table with appropriate index;
   }
```

use

```
       array[hash(str)]
```

to do what you want. This is my idea there may be some other best ways too. or some libraries (eg: Boost) may 've associative array.

Comment: @Max will this accomplish your intent?

Comment: Thank you,

I think so.
My problem is I don't know the value of "s1" or "s2" etc until run-time (I am reading in a file and going from there).

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a hash map or hash table (two names for the same thing). Those are not arrays, even if they are incorrectly named so in some languages <sup>(I'm look at you, PHP)</sup>. An array is per definition a memory area indexed with an offset into the area, which means you must index it with numbers.

A hash map applies a hash function on the keys before looking them up, so they transform the string key into a number.

Comment: They are associative arrays.  Calling them arrays is still quite valid.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array  In fact, using the word hash is too specific, as the question doesn't necessarily care if the implementation involves a hash at all.  What he wants is an array of data associated in a certain way.